# Getting below error while running ruby script

Tags: ruby, groovy, rubygems, soapui, watir-webdriver

I am running a test suite in Soap UI where I am trying to call one ruby script from groovy script. The step is getting executed successfully but still the script is not able to move on to the next step as it gives this error after running.
Have searched in google about this error, but found no proper resolution. Moreover the error itself is not very explanatory.

Will appreciate any kind of help.
Below is the groovy script which is calling "ap-v4-batch_DEV_QA.rb" ruby script.
This ruby script opens a browser and performs the task successfully and closes the browser. We expect the step to be marked as Passed so that it can move on to the next step, but it gives the error mentioned at the bottom.

Groovy Script:

```
String script = "webdriver/v4/ap-v4-batch_DEV_QA.rb";
String argv0 = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("GLOB_DefaultIP");
String argv1 = "com.wupay.batch.process.tasks.PaymentFileParsingTask_RunOnce";
String argv2 = "";
String argv3 = "";
String argv4 = "";

/* Nothing needs to be modified below */
String commandLine = "ruby " + com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("GLOB_ScriptLocation") + "/" + script + " " + argv0 + " " + argv1 + " " + argv2 + " " + argv3 + " " + argv4;
log.info("Running command line: " + commandLine);

java.lang.Runtime runtime = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
java.lang.Process p = runtime.exec(commandLine);

def propertyStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");
java.io.BufferedReader stdInput = 
    new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
java.io.BufferedReader stdError = 
    new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String s = null;
String e = null;
StringBuffer eb = new StringBuffer();
while ((e = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
    eb.append(e);
    log.error("Ruby: " + e);
}
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    log.info("Ruby: " + s);
    if(s.startsWith("@prop")) {
        String[] propSplit = s.split(":", 3);
        testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(propSplit[1], propSplit[2]);
    }
}
p.waitFor();

log.info("Ruby: exit value " + p.exitValue());
if(eb.length() > 0) {
    throw new Exception(eb.toString());
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.Exception: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require':`require "watir-webdriver"`is deprecated. Please, use`require "watir"`. java.lang.Exception: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in`require': `require "watir-webdriver"` is deprecated. Please, use `require "watir"`. error at line: 57

Comment: `require "watir-webdriver"is deprecated. Please, userequire "watir".`

Comment: Sorry, should I use require "watir". Will that help?
I had even tried that previously, but got the same error.

Don't mind, can you please elaborate the answer.

Comment: You may now need to show both groovy script and ruby script as well in order get any help.

Comment: Have added the groovy script for your kind reference

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved the issue.
The issue was that ruby script was not accepting require "watir-webdriver".

I installed watir and replaced require "watir-webdriver" with require "watir".
now I am not getting the above mentioned error.

Thanks anyways!

Regards,
Faraz